# I need driver for D-link DWA-185(rtl8822b) for ubuntu 20.04 to be installed

Tags: ubuntu-drivers, d-link

I have some issues with wifi adapter D-link DWA-185 (rtl8822b).
This adapter didn't work on my ubuntu 20.04 (kernel was 5.4 but I upgraded it to 5.9.12) when I switch it on. Then I went to support site and found driver for linux
https://www.dlink.ru/ru/products/2/2432.html. It's a bit wierd but I couldn't find similar information about this goods at main dlink site https://support.dlink.com/index.aspx.

Then I run into some difficulties when try it to setup. I couldn't find any executable sh-file to run installation for ubuntu(linux), a lot of possible variants (a lot of android and so on) but what should I do if I want to install it on ubuntu?

Could you share with me the info how to setup driver for such kind of stuff?

```
 lspci
```

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)

- when I attach TL-WN722N (works well)

  lsusb

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
  ```
- when I attach DWA-815

  lsusb

  ```
   Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
  ```

On Windows 10 adapter DWA-815 works well.

Comment: Wireless cards that use a Realtek rtl8822b should work without any special drivers in Ubuntu 20.04 as the card has been available for a number of years. Do you see the wireless device when you type `lspci` into the terminal?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: updated info post... I've heard that DWA-185 should work only with kernel upper 5.7, that's why I upgraded it to 5.9, but unfortunately it didn't help me  to run out of the box.

Comment: Please see my answer at the duplicate. The driver builds perfectly on my 5.8 kernel and I suspect it will also for you.

Comment: Yes, bro,  you saved my day! It helped me.